# Date validation in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to validate the date entered in the format dd/mm/yyyy. Using exceptionvalidation I can validate correctly only if the date is entered in the format mm/dd/yyyy. Can anyone suggest some workarounds?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear; what code do you use for validation? Also, assuming it's v4, I think you'd be better off using IDataErrorInfo. But it really all depends on the code.

Answer (score 0):

try doing two validations, i assume you are validating a string using DateTime.Parse.

On the second validation try specifying a culture which uses ddmmyyyy format, such as Australia